# Vue 2.0 vueify browserify-simple :: Autoprefixer Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, browserify, autoprefixer

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I've asked around everywhere, but autoprefixer is just not working.

I started with this template:
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify-simple

I installed autoprefixer:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
```

My vue.config.js file is in the root of my project. I added this to my vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  postcss: [
    require('autoprefixer')({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'IE 10']
    })
  ]
}

console.log('is this working?')
```

Not only does autoprefixer not prefix anything, but the log doesn't get output either. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configure setting.

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
module.exports = {
  // provide your own postcss plugins 
  postcss: [require('autoprefixer')({
    browsers: ['last 50 versions']
  })]
}
```